# Disabling clang-tidy diagnostic

Tags: c, clang, naming-conventions, clang-tidy

I'm trying to set up `clang-tidy` for enforcing naming conventions in a C project. This project is composed of multiple external sources and uses a plain makefile environment, thus no tool like `cmake` or `bear` is available to generate a compilation database.

This is also what I want: Using the custom environment I'd like to selectively invoke `clang-tidy` for each file that should be checked.

I was configuring the tool, mainly for the check `readability-identifier-naming`. For testing I have a `.c` and `.h` file, both in the same directory, with the following content:

**dummy.c**

```
#include "dummy.h"
#include "MISSING_module.h"

// EOF
```

**dummy.h**

```
#ifndef _DUMMY_H_
#define _DUMMY_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

// EOF
```

The command I'm invoking is

```
clang-tidy dummy.c -checks='-*,readability-identifier-naming' -- -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON`
```

However, `clang-tidy` is still following the `#include` within the C-file and checks for existing headers:

```
dummy.h:4:10: error: 'stdlib.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <stdlib.h>
          ^
Found compiler error(s).
```

Is there any way to disable this? `clang-diagnostic-error` is not even enabled as check. Or are there alternative tools I should know of to enforce naming conventions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the way you are using clang-tidy: the `--` option is used to specify **compilation** options.

`clang-diagnostic-error` doesn't have anything to do with clang-tidy itself. Those are compiler warnings and you cannot turn them off. Clang-tidy needs the analyzed file to be compile-able to build an AST which it uses internally for the checks. You'll find more on `clang-diagnostic-error` in [clang-tidy documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#id2).

Comment: For me it wasn't quite obvious that `clang-tidy` actually needs to invoke a compiler. The docs are rather short so that was hard to understand, I've worked with different static analyzers that wouldn't need it. In the end I'm now generating a compilation database with `gmake` and python.